# P reduction between np-complete to np-complete

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, turing-machines, reductions

given 2 lagnauges A,B which are npc.
is there a reduction function from A to B $A \leq_PB$ ?

my idea was to say that since they are decideable, 
we can do this:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} y \in B & \text{ } if x \in A \\y \notin B & \text{if }x \notin A.\end{cases}
$$

is this is correct? or its not something that can be true? / depands on p equal or not equal to np

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: What is the definition of "**NP**-complete"?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than spoon-feeding you the answer, I will tell you how to find the answer for yourself.

I suggest you write out the definition for the notation $\le_P$.  Then, check whether your reduction meets the criteria for that notation.

> Hint: the $P$ is important.